# Convert rmarkdown .Rmd file to (knitr) sweave (.Rnw)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I have a rmarkdown document (`.Rmd`) that I've been doing some analysis in. I now realize I would prefer the functionality of LaTeX. Is there an easy way to convert the file to `.Rnw`, preserving the chunks (not just the body text)? Articles seem to concentrate on converting the output (i.e. from `.html` to `.pdf`) or from sweave to markdown.

Comment: My guess would be that you will have to replace all chunks in your `.Rmd` by some placeholders, resulting in a valid markdown `.md`. Then use pandoc to convert it to latex, and, by hand, put all chunks back in and rename it to `.Rnw`. (BTW: are you really sure about sweave? I found going from sweave to knitr/markdown such a relief: not having to debug both my latex _and_ my R code.)

Comment: There's nothing *inside* your chunks that needs to be changed. Only the syntax for chunk start and chunk end is different: *```{r chunkname, options}* vs. *<<chunkname, options>>=*.